# Gitlab CICD pm2 cmd ot found

Tags: continuous-integration, command, pm2, cd

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.7.0 (102c81ba)
  on nova hywQGeM7, system ID: s_caed77639cb7
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell (bash) executor...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on ip-172-31-2-77...
Getting source from Git repository
00:01
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/hywQGeM7/0/g1335/novacxbackend/.git/
Checking out f710786e as detached HEAD (ref is main)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
$ pm2 stop all
bash: line 141: pm2: command not found
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

can anyone help me i had installed pm2 node, in server then also its showing pm2 cmd not found